# How to generate short unique names for uploaded files in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload, uniqueidentifier

I need to name uploaded files by short unique identifier like `nYrnfYEv` `a4vhAoFG` `hwX6aOr7`. How could I ensure uniqueness of files?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript

Comment: From the first comment of this post: `Warning: None of the answers have a true-random result! They are only pseudo-random. When using random strings for protection or security, don't use any of them!!! Try one of these api's` I need to realy unique names

Comment: @Erik you can check my answer now

Comment: Check [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid). It sounds exactly like the one you're looking for.

Comment: Is it generate unique not repeated ids?

Comment: @Erik no it's still something probabilistic. Which isn't necessarily bad, depending on the requirements.

Comment: @Qualcuno I need generate completlly unique ids

Comment: @Erik then either you check the id against a database (or the filesystem), or you add a timestamp at the beginning of the file name. Modules like shortid are designed so the chance for collisions is extremely low, almost 0, and if you prepend something like a timestamp you can be 100% certain it's never going to result in a collision (and it's pretty hard to guess too)

Comment: Ok, but why modules like shortid don't add something like a timestamp to be sure it's 100% unique?

Answer (score 25):

**Update:** [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) is deprecated. Use [Nano ID](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/) instead. The answer below applies to Nano ID as well.

---

(Posting my comments as answer, with responses to your concerns)

You may want to check out the [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) NPM module, which generates short ids (shockingly, I know :) ) similar to the ones you were posting as example. The result is configurable, but by default it's a string between 7 and 14 characters (length is random too), all URL-friendly (`A-Za-z0-9\_\-` in a regex).

To answer your (and other posters') concerns:

- Unless your server has a true random number generator (highly unlikely), every solution will use a PRNG (Pseudo-Random Number Generator). shortid uses Node.js crypto module to generate PRNG numbers, however, which is a much better generator than Math.random()
- shortid's are not sequential, which makes it even harder to guess them
- While shortid's are not guaranteed to be unique, the likelihood of a collision is extremely small. Unless you generate billions of entries per year, you could safely assume that a collision will never happen.
- For most cases, relying on probability to trust that collisions won't happen is enough. If your data is too important to risk even that tiny amount, you could make the shortid *basically* 100% unique by just prepending a timestamp to it. As an additional benefit, the file names will be harder to guess too. (Note: I wrote "basically 100% unique" because you could still, in theory, have a collision if two items are generated in the same timestamp, i.e. the same second. However, I would never be concerned of this. To have a real 100% certainty your only option is to run a check against a database or the filesystem, but that requires more resources.)
- The reason why shortid doesn't do that by itself is because for most applications the likelihood of a collision is too small to be a concern, and it's more important to have the shortest possible ids.

Comment: Appending a timestamp isn't necessary. shortid [ensures multiple calls within the same second generate unique IDs](https://github.com/dylang/shortid/blob/master/lib/build.js#L15).

Comment: @RichardPoole That's exactly why I'm suggesting adding the timestamp as an option (absolutely not necessary). In different seconds, the same ID could _theoretically_ be generated again. This of course depends on how many IDs you generate, and all the points I made above stand valid

Comment: An approach I've been using, regardless of the generator used (it could be shortid or xxhash, for instance) is incrementing an integer counter each time a file is uploaded that essentially keeps track of the number of files that were uploaded since the server is running and to insert this counter in the seed for the filename. With this method combined with inserting a unix timestamp, I don't see any collision possible, unless you upload 2^53 files without ever restarting your server.

Comment: In fact, for a collision to happen using this method, 2^53 files would have to be uploaded in one second, I'm fairly certain that's impossible.

Comment: @Gaboik1the problem with that is that you need a way to store the unique index - for example a database. It will take two DB calls on every ID generation: one to read the index, and another one to update it. With shortId (et similia) plus the timestamp, chances of a collision are already incredibly small, even at large scale. It's also stateless and so suitable for using with distributed systems, without a centralized database/repository which would be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 19):

One option could be to generate unique identifiers (UUID) and rename the file(s) accordingly.

Have a look at the [`kelektiv/node-uuid`](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid/) npm module.

---

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$ npm install uuid
```

...then in your JavaScript file:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4'); // I chose v4 ‒ you can select others
var filename = uuidv4(); // '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

Any time you execute `uuidv4()` you'll get a **very-fresh-new-one**.

> **NOTICE:** There are other choices/types of UUIDs. Read the module's documentation to familiarize with those.

Comment: I need to name uploaded files.

Comment: @Erik: That's why. You receive some stream from somewhere, and when you save it, you name it. Even so, you can rename it.

Comment: @ Machina yes but I still need to generate unique name

Comment: why the sudo? IMHO, npm install --save node-uuid

Comment: It's a bad idea to shorten UUIDs, as it doesn't guarantee uniqueness when you shorten them.

Answer (score 5):

Very simple code. produce a filename almost unique
or if that's not enough you check if the file exists

```
function getRandomFileName() {
var timestamp = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-:.]/g,"");  
var random = ("" + Math.random()).substring(2, 8); 
var random_number = timestamp+random;  
return random_number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
export default generateRandom = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(23).substring(2, 5);
```

As simple as that!

Comment: This is nice and functional for some simple usecases

Answer (score 0):

```
function uniqueFileName( filePath, stub)
{
    let id = 0;
    let test = path.join(filePath, stub + id++);
    while (fs.existsSync(test))
    {
        test = path.join(filePath, stub + id++);
    }
    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetTempName()
{
    function gen(count) 
    { 
        let str = '';
        for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) 
        {
            str += Math.floor(Math.random() * "0123456789abcdef".length).toString(36);
        }
        return  str;
    }
    return gen(8)+'-'+gen(4)+'-'+gen(4)+'-'+gen(4)+'-'+gen(12);
    //return gen(5);
    
}

console.log(GetTempName());
```

Answer (score -5):

I think you might be confused about true-random and pseudo-random.

Pseudo-random strings 'typically exhibit stastical randomness while being generated by an entirely deterministic casual process'. What this means is, if you are using these random values as entropy in a cryptographic application, you do not want to use a pseudo-random generator.

For your use, however, I believe it will be fine - just check for potential (highly unlikely) clashes.

All you are wanting to do is create a random string - not ensure it is 100% secure and completely random.

Comment: Unless you have a TRNG hardware module, which is highly unlikely, every software solution uses a PRNG. Some, however, are "more random": using Node.js `crypto` module, for example, is a better PRNG than `Math.random()`.

Answer (score -6):

Try following snippet:-

```
    function getRandomSalt() {
    var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
    var timestamp = (milliseconds.toString()).substring(9, 13)
    var random = ("" + Math.random()).substring(2, 8);
    var random_number = timestamp+random;  // string will be unique because timestamp never repeat itself
    var random_string = base64_encode(random_number).substring(2, 8); // you can set size here of return string
    var return_string = '';
    var Exp = /((^[0-9]+[a-z]+)|(^[a-z]+[0-9]+))+[0-9a-z]+$/i;
    if (random_string.match(Exp)) {                 //check here whether string is alphanumeric or not
        return_string = random_string;
    } else {
        return getRandomSalt();  // call recursivley again
    }
    return return_string;
}
```

File name might have an alphanumeric name with uniqueness according to your requirement. Unique name based on the concept of timestamp of current time because current time never repeat itself in future and to make it strong i have applied a [base64encode](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/) which will be convert it into alphanumeric.

```
   var file = req.files.profile_image;
   var tmp_path = file.path;
   var fileName = file.name;
   var file_ext = fileName.substr((Math.max(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) || Infinity) + 1);
   var newFileName = getRandomSalt() + '.' + file_ext;
```

Thanks

Comment: `getRandomSalt` always generates same string

Comment: Thanks for the code. How much a chanse that we get repeated id?

Comment: Never. Its a combination of timestamp and random number. After that base64 encoding has been done. You can check through billions of data and verify my answer after that.

Comment: it would be great if you choose large string as a return string of getRandomSalt function

Comment: the comment about timestamp never repeating itself is perhaps misleading. When I type `for(i=0; i < 60; ++i) console.log(new Date().getTime());` I can see the timestamp repeat itself dozens of times. I suppose the comment is correct if you're running on a machine where the rest of the code is guaranteed to consume more than a millisecond. Either way, most of the timestamp string is not changing, and therefore contributing very little to the uniqueness. I ran this on node and got a collision in the first 60 iterations. Ran it 600 times, got a stack overflow (try to prove the recursion halts!).